# How to set 2d Vector by X,Y ids as you would a 2dArray?

Tags: java

Given a 2dArray I can directly set any element by specifying the X,Y index as such:

```
2dArray[row][col] = "hello";
```

How can I accomplish the same thing with a 2D Vector or 2D ArrayList? It seems like I would need to recreate the entire column vector if i want to change any element within it, and then reset that column vector into the row.

I'm working on a simple tilebased game, so the ability to directly get/set by X,Y index is quite handy.

Thoughts? Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Why an arraylist or a vector? For a tilebased game, your approach with the 2d-array seems right to me. Remember that deleting and inserting in the middle of an ArrayList is quite expensive (`O(n)` if I remember correctly). In an array, it's `O(1)`

Comment: @Atmocreations ArrayLists are backed by arrays.

Comment: @Atmocreations It's `O(n)` for both ArrayList and Array. You're probably thinking of LinkedList which is `O(1)` (since every delete/add requires a constant number of link changes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your list is a `List<List<T>>` then, `list.get(x).set(y, elem)` get(x) identifies the row then set(y, elem) sets the y-th element of the row (which is in the y-th column) to elem

Answer (score 1):

you could make a class for it.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class AClass<T>
{
    public Store2D()
    {
        coords = new LinkedList<List<T>>();
    }
    public void set(int x, int y, T value)
    {
        coords.get(x).set(y, value);
    }
    public T get(int x, int y)
    {
        return coords.get(x).get(y);
    }
    List<List<T>> coords;
}
```

Then to use it:

```
AClass<String> vector = new AClass<String>();

AClass.set(13, 17, "Hello");
AClass.set(17, 13, "World");
System.out.println(AClass.get(13, 17)+" "+AClass.get(17, 13));
```

Output = "Hello World"